# Conditional JS and CSS files not being loaded on Wordpress pages

Tags: php, wordpress, dynamic, blogs

We have a Wordpress site that was built for us by consultants and everything was working fine until recently.  We're seeing this page missing both CSS (posts.css) and JS (slick.js) file includes for some reason.

Page in question: https://kmbs.konicaminolta.us/blog/

As you can see, it has some issues.  The page looked correct back in July 2022, as per the wayback machine archive:  https://web.archive.org/web/20220717052205/https://kmbs.konicaminolta.us/blog/

posts.css and slick.js are included on that page from July.  The PHP logic is supposed to check if the page needs those files and automatically place them there:

```
fx_assets_add_script(
        [
            'handle'        => 'fx_slick',
            'src'           => $theme_url . '/assets/js/plugins/slick.js',
            'dependencies'  => [ 'jquery', 'fx_choices' ],
            'enqueue'       => is_archive() || is_home() || is_page('promotions') || is_page('press-releases') || is_page('news-insights') || is_page('newsroom')
        ]
    );
```

and

```
fx_assets_add_stylesheet(
        [
            'handle'    => 'site-posts',
            'src'       => $theme_url . '/assets/css/posts.css',
            'enqueue'   => ( is_single() || is_page('promotions') || is_home() || is_archive() || is_search() || is_author() || is_page('newsroom') || is_page('press-releases') || is_page('news-insights') || is_page('security-announcements') )
        ]
    );
```

Not sure if the above need: is_page('blog') in the 'enqueue' line, but I tried that and it didn't seem to fix the issue (I cleared WP Rocket cache and CDN cache).  Or do I need to restart the server for that change to take effect?  Of course it could be any number of other things - maybe - such as recent plugin updates, etc.

Any thoughts or suggestions on how to resolve this issue?  (Besides going back to the consultants that built the thing.)  We could add the missing code to a file that does get pulled onto every page, but that defeats the purpose of the conditional / dynamic loading, of course.

As you may have guessed, this is not the only page that's impacted.  If we can find the solution to this though, it may be the solution to the other page issues as well.

Thanks.

Comment: For this exact moment in time you could probably just set both of those to `true`, they're only 15KB uncompressed, and when WP Rocket combines them and HTTP compression kicks in, they won't amount to much.

Comment: @ChrisHaas  Could you clarify exactly what you mean by "set both of those to true"?  Thanks.

Comment: Change the `'enqueue' => ...` to `'enqueue'   => true`.

Comment: That seems to work.  Anyone have any idea why the original 'enqueue' => lines would seemingly suddenly stop working?